# Add Coun Expression in Join to Magento Collection

Tags: sql, magento, zend-db

Hi guys I'm having a hard time adding a join in Magento, well I know I can do `$collection->getSelect()->join` but I need to add a `Count()` expression in it.

What I'm concretly trying to achieve is this query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, COUNT(sfoi.product_id) as `count`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` 
AS `e` 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi
ON sfoi.product_id = e.entity_id 
ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` asc, 
`e`.`entity_id` asc
```

Edit:

THis is what it looks like now:

```
$e = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSelect();
$e->join(array('c' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
'e.entity_id = c.product_id',
array('count' => 'COUNT(c.product_id)'));
```

Outputting this gives:

```
SELECT `e`.*, COUNT(c.product_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` 
AS `e` INNER         
JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `c` ON e.entity_id = c.product_id
```

doing this in my collection crashes the adminhtml grid.
Tracing the reports it crashes here:

`a:5:{i:0;s:35:"Unrecognized method 'setPageSize()'";i:1;s:4771:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(504): Zend_Db_Select->__call('setPageSize', Array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply any `Zend_Db_Select` method to the object returned by `getSelect()`.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

You can use `COUNT()` in the `join()` method and there are a couple of examples on the page, in particular see the first example under section 'Adding a GROUP BY Clause':

```
->join(array('l' => 'line_items'),
    'p.product_id = l.product_id',
    array('line_items_per_product' => 'COUNT(*)'))
```